# Kann man "mit sich ziehen" sagen?

Tags: phrase

Soweit ich weiß, kann man entweder

> etw. mit sich bringen

oder

> etw. nach sich ziehen

sagen.
Existiert allerdings eine Mischform von den beiden Wendungen?

> etw. mit sich ziehen

Comment: Eher nur im ursprünglichen Wortsinn: Eine Lokomotive kann viele Anhänger mit sich ziehen. Aber selbst dann wird die Wendung sehr selten verwendet und klingt auch seltsam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es existiert die Mischform. Mit sich ziehen bedeutet, das man etwas mit erhält, was man eigentlich nicht möchte. Beispiel: der Einzug der AfD in den Bundestag wird Probleme für die Regierung mit sich ziehen.